# How is the system classloader in java useful?

Tags: java, classloader

I expect the system classloader to take over class loading for my application. So, if I run my program as,

```
java -Djava.system.class.loader=MyClassLoader Main
```

I expect Main to be loaded by MyClassLoader so that I can control class loading within my application. But that does not happen. Main is still loaded by the default system class loader (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader), as are other classes referenced from Main. However, calls to getSystemClassLoader() return an instance of MyClassLoader.

How is this useful? Wouldn't it make sense for Main to be loaded by my custom system class loader? How do I take control of class loading for my application? And who uses the getSystemClassLoader() value?

Comment: Something has to load your class loader.... and that is the system classloader (which is magically inside the JVM).

Comment: And how did you implement your classloader? Do you perhaps delegate to the parent?

Comment: I think, if split logic and Main method to two classes then Main will load by system but logic by your, but I can be wrong , check this situation

Comment: @Basile Of course, my class loader will be loaded by the default system class loader. But why isn't my main class loaded by my class loader?

Comment: Debug your classloader. My guess is, it gets a shot at loading the class, but misses its opportunity.

Comment: @Marko I haven't written my own class loader. I merely extended the URLClassLoader. I'm just trying to figure out the uses of overriding the system class loader.

Comment: OK, so you didn't write it from scratch, but it's still your class. You must first disprove this hypothesis: *Your classloader is being invoked, but it delegates to the parent classloader*.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @Marko I see, so main is loaded by the default system class loader because my class loader is delegating to that. Is that correct?

Comment: That is a hypothesis which I can neither prove nor disprove, but you can. It is the place to start diagnosing your situation.

Comment: Please post the code of your ClassLoader

Comment: @Marko Yep, that was it. URLClassLoader was delegating to the parent. I overrode loadClass() and managed to return the class myself. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer, then, to satisfy the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

If you just subclassed `URLClassLoader` with no overriding, [this is the documented behaviour you should expect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL%5b%5d%29):

> The URLs will be searched in the order specified for classes and resources after first searching in the parent class loader.

If the parent class loader can load the class, then it does so, and the loader reported for that class will be the parent class loader. In order to revert this *parent-first* classloading policy that is the default for Java classloaders, you must override `loadClass`.